# Set RelativeLayout background to full transparent in Android Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have created a xml layout for popup dialog. There I created a CardView with an image on the top of it.

Everything working fine but half of the background of the image should be fully transparent which means no views should be visible. I have tried setting alpha value but it's not working as expected. It is hiding all views. I have also tried `@android:color:transparent`.

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Total Project"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="100" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearbox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linear_text"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorGrayLight" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="Project Live"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="5"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorGrayLight" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorGrayLight" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="Project Wip"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="5"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorGrayLight" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorGrayLight" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="Project Closed"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="5"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/admin"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Dialog:

```
  private void showDialog() {
    // creating the fullscreen dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    if (dialog.getWindow() != null) {
        //  dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your imageview code as shown below.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" 
    android:translationZ="10dp"/>
```

What i have changes in this code is added the parameter **android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"** this will bring image view in center and also added **android:translationZ="10dp"** this will aloways keep the imageview above other layouts.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can add alpha to background color to make an image transparent.

```
public static int getColorWithAlpha(int color, int alpha) {
    int red = Color.red(color);
    int green = Color.green(color);
    int blue = Color.blue(color);
    return Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
}
```